# How to efficiently store a constant stream of stats

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, webrtc, usage-statistics

*I'm sure this has been asked dozens of times but I can't seem to find the correct terms to google for to get the info I need.*

I look after a video streaming platform built in Asp.Net MVC 5.2. We film and stream live events. Some of our events have thousands of users watching at a time, sometimes it's only a couple of dozen.

We need to store watching statistics both to know how many users we had watching AND also how much they watched.

This is especially important for some clients who need to know if specific users watched training sessions all the way through.

The current thinking is that we will periodically (once a minute or so). Fire an ajax call off to the server which will store the info via Entity Framework.

Our concerns are:

- Will we hit a concurrent connections limit and bring the site down? If so how do we protect against this (some kind of caching before writing, maybe Redis?).
- Is Ajax the right approach, should we use SignalR or some other WebRTC method and if so can we make it work on older and mobile browsers (IE9, Safari, etc)?
- Will this much data become too unwieldy and take forever to read / write once the table gets big?

We're completely open to using something other than our current SQL Server approach but I can't find the right thing to Google for to find an appropriate solution.

So, can anyone either tell me what I should be searching for (ie is there a name for this requirement) or perhaps make some suggestions of products or tutorials that cover this?

Thanks,

Comment: Unfortunately this is _far_ too broad of a question for Stack Overflow

Comment: Can you recommend a more appropriate forum of developers to ask?

Comment: Possibly reddit?

Comment: As I do agree with @maccettura with this question being too broad. I do suggest you can achieve what you are looking to do with [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) as a user connects to the stream they will connect with a signalr client to a hub. This is a concurrent connection as long as the user is connected. This could get you all the info you would need. It would let you know who is connected, how long they are connected etc. SignalR is also very useful for live chat as well. I would suggest you taking a look.

Comment: I will also add that Entity Framework is not very optimized and would be a poor choice for speed/performance

Comment: I did this a long time ago using the Google Analytics plugin for JW Player. We didn't have to worry about concurrency (because it's Google), and all the reports we needed were already included in the dashboard. https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1417179#fndtn-dashboard